# check my links format with php

Tags: php, format, hyperlink

I have something like this :

```
<?php

$siteurl = "http://www.example.com/";

$pageid = "ed2689";

$pageurl = $siteurl.$pageid;

?>
```

and the links will be like this:

http://www.example.com/ed2689

http://www.example.com/report/ed2689

I have used preg_match to check the format for each one of this links

for the first link, it must be exactly like this:

$siteurl.[a-z0-9]

and i have used this :

```
if (preg_match('/[$siteurl]+[a-z0-9]/', $pageurl) && !preg_match('/[=]|[?]/', $pageurl))
{
echo 'Ok',
}
```

and for for the second link, it must be exactly like this:

$siteurl.'report/'.[a-z0-9]

and i have used this :

```
if (preg_match('/[$siteurl]+[report]+[a-z0-9]/', $req_uri) && !preg_match('/[=]|[?]/', $req_uri))
{
echo 'Ok',
}
```

and it doesn't work correctly..any help please ?

Thanks.

Comment: What about if you use `"` instead of `'` ? Variables inside `' '` doesn't get evaluated. Also, the `?` is special, consider scaping it with `\`

Comment: +1 for a clear question with a clear problem. Maybe give us examples of how the "incorrect" results are though?

Comment: @Jonast92, ok just aminute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if not works

```
<?php
    $siteurl = 'http://www.example.com/report/ed2689';
    //$siteurl = 'http://www.example.com/ed2689';
    if(strpos($siteurl,'www.example.com') === false) echo 'not my site';
    else {
        $arr = explode('www.example.com/',$siteurl);
        $suburl = trim($arr[1]);
        if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+$/', $suburl) || preg_match('/^report\/[a-z0-9]+$/', $suburl))
        {
        echo 'ok';
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Please, why you added +$ ?

Comment: + means [a-z0-9] can be present multiple time. and at least one. $ means no more character are allowed

Comment: nothing wrong with your code :) if i want to add / before the "report" word for a part of link "/report/ed2689" preg_match should like "preg_match('/^\report\.....) right ?